# ListFragment inside Linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to put a list under buttons and text view.
what is the best option.

I am now trying to use fragment under linear layout.

However my app crashes in onCreate (I guess so),

**this on the log:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.javacodegeeks.android.datepickerexample/com.javacodegeeks.android.datepickerexample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class fragment
```

here is the code:

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ch_label" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_start_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ch_start_time_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_end_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ch_end_time_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cur_date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/start_time_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/end_time_picker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <fragment android:name="com.javadocsgeeks.android.datepickerexample"
            android:id="@+id/c_sms_list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout >
```

**row_view.xml for each row in the list (ListFragment)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" 
    android:text="CheckedTextView" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView text_date;
    private DatePicker date_picker;
    private TimePicker start_time_picker;
    private TimePicker end_time_picker;
    private Button date_button;
    private Button start_time_button;
    private Button end_time_button;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    private int start_hour;
    private int start_minute;   


    private int end_hour;
    private int end_minute; 

    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID       = 100;
    static final int START_TIME_DIALOG_ID = 101;
    static final int END_TIME_DIALOG_ID   = 102;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        setCurrentDate();
        addButtonListener();

    }

    // display current date both on the text view and the Date Picker
    public void setCurrentDate() {

        text_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_date);
        date_picker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        start_time_picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.start_time_picker);
        end_time_picker   = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.end_time_picker);

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        start_hour = 7;
        start_minute = 0;
        end_hour += 8;
        end_minute = 0;

        String date_string = new StringBuilder()
                                .append(day).append("-")
                                .append(month + 1).append("-")
                                .append(year).append(" ").toString();
        String start_time_string = new StringBuilder()
                                .append(" START time ")
                                .append(pad(start_hour)).append(":")    
                                .append(pad(start_minute)).append(" ").toString();  

        String end_time_string = new StringBuilder()
                                .append(" END    time ")
                                .append(pad(end_hour)).append(":")  
                                .append(pad(end_minute)).append(" ").toString();        

        // set current date into textview
        text_date.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based, so you have to add 1
            .append(date_string)
            .append(start_time_string)
            .append(end_time_string)
            );

        // set current date into Date Picker
        date_picker.init(year, month, day, null);
        date_picker.setVisibility(DatePicker.GONE);
        date_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
        date_button.setText(date_string);       
        start_time_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start_time);
        end_time_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_end_time);          
        initTimePickerAndButton(start_time_picker, start_hour, start_minute, start_time_button, start_time_string);
        initTimePickerAndButton(end_time_picker, end_hour, end_minute, end_time_button, end_time_string);
    }

    public void addButtonListener() {

        // Date Picker
        date_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);

        date_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

            }

        });
        // Start Time Picker
        start_time_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start_time);

        start_time_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(START_TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }
        });             
        // End Time Picker
        end_time_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_end_time);

        end_time_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showDialog(END_TIME_DIALOG_ID);

            }           

        });     


    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
           // set date picker as current date
           return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,day);
        case START_TIME_DIALOG_ID:
           // set date picker as current date
           return new TimePickerDialog(this, startTimePickerListener, start_hour, start_minute, false);
        case END_TIME_DIALOG_ID:
               // set date picker as current date
               return new TimePickerDialog(this, endTimePickerListener, end_hour, end_minute, false);          
        }       
        return null;
    }


    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into Text View
            text_date.setText(new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based, so you have to add 1
                .append(day).append("-")
                .append(month + 1).append("-")
                .append(year).append(" ")
                .append(year).append(" at time ")
                .append(pad(start_hour)).append(":")    
                .append(pad(start_minute)).append(" ")
                    );

            // set selected date into Date Picker
            date_picker.init(year, month, day, null);

        }
    };


        private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener startTimePickerListener =  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                start_hour = selectedHour;
                start_minute = selectedMinute;

                String date_string = new StringBuilder()
                                        .append(day).append("-")
                                        .append(month + 1).append("-")
                                        .append(year).append(" ").toString();
                String start_time_string = new StringBuilder()
                                        .append(" start time ")
                                        .append(pad(start_hour)).append(":")    
                                        .append(pad(start_minute)).append(" ").toString();  

                String end_time_string = new StringBuilder()
                                        .append(" start time ")
                                        .append(pad(end_hour)).append(":")  
                                        .append(pad(end_minute)).append(" ").toString();        

                // set current date into textview
                text_date.setText(new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based, so you have to add 1
                    .append(date_string)
                    .append(start_time_string)
                    .append(end_time_string)
                    );

                initTimePickerAndButton(start_time_picker, start_hour, start_minute, start_time_button, start_time_string);

            }
        };

        private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener endTimePickerListener =  new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                end_hour = selectedHour;
                end_minute = selectedMinute;

                String date_string = new StringBuilder()
                                        .append(day).append("-")
                                        .append(month + 1).append("-")
                                        .append(year).append(" ").toString();
                String start_time_string = new StringBuilder()
                                        .append(" start time ")
                                        .append(pad(start_hour)).append(":")    
                                        .append(pad(start_minute)).append(" ").toString();  

                String end_time_string = new StringBuilder()
                                        .append(" start time ")
                                        .append(pad(end_hour)).append(":")  
                                        .append(pad(end_minute)).append(" ").toString();        

                // set current date into textview
                text_date.setText(new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based, so you have to add 1
                    .append(date_string)
                    .append(start_time_string)
                    .append(end_time_string)
                    );
                    initTimePickerAndButton(end_time_picker, end_hour, end_minute, end_time_button, end_time_string);

            }
        };

        private static String pad(int c) {
            if (c >= 10)
               return String.valueOf(c);
            else
               return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
        }

        private void initTimePickerAndButton(TimePicker time_picker, int hour, int minute, Button time_button, String time_string) {
            time_picker.setVisibility(TimePicker.GONE);
            time_picker.setIs24HourView(Boolean.TRUE);
            time_picker.setCurrentHour(hour);
            time_picker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
            time_button.setText(time_string);           
        }


}
```

c_sms_list.java (this is the fragment which I want it to be list)

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.datepickerexample;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment ;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class c_sms_list extends ListFragment  {

  @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",
        "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
        "t", "u", "w", "x", "y", "z" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // do something with the data
  }
}
```

Comment: Does answer of @blackbelt solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

Update your main.xml:

```
<fragment android:name="com.javadocsgeeks.android.datepickerexample"
android:id="@+id/c_sms_list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

=>

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/c_sms_list">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Update your main activity, add the below code into bottom of onCreate method:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction trans = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
c_sms_list yourFrag = new c_sms_list();
trans.add(R.id.c_sms_list, yourFrag);
trans.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

why you calling super.onCreate() in onActivityCreated function

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    //... your code
}
```

to :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);  // change from calling onCreate to onActivityCreated
    //... your code
}
```

and in your main xml file in fragment tag in name attributes you missed fragment class name
so change this

```
<fragment android:name="com.javadocsgeeks.android.datepickerexample"
  other attributes = ""
 />
```

to

```
<fragment android:name="com.javadocsgeeks.android.datepickerexample.c_sms_list"
  other attributes = ""
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

you missed the name of the fragment in the xml:

```
<fragment android:name="com.javadocsgeeks.android.datepickerexample.c_sms_list"
```

[here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html#AddInLayout) you can find the documentation